# Angularjs md-sidenav left not work

Tags: css, angularjs, sidenav

I have test project AngularJS and .net
https://github.com/HelenSPR/TestAngularjsFabricjs

I create sidenav as https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.4/demo/sidenav but my sidenav show as row and not as column, this sidenav don't hide.

What am I doing wrong?